# Android Dialog root view

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I have a dialog in Android, as a layout I use this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


</ListView>
```

In the Activity I need to add a Adapter to this ListView, I have this:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id){
    case ADDPLAYERDIALOG:{
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);            
        d.setContentView(R.layout.training_dialog);
        ListView lv = (ListView) d.getCurrentFocus().getRootView(); 
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, createNamesList());   
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);     

    return d;
    }
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

I get a NullPointerException here:

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) d.getCurrentFocus().getRootView();
```

I don't have the id for this ListView widget, because it is a layout XML-file, and I can't just write `lv = d.findViewById(R.id.listview);`

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you actually tried giving it an id? I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily set an id through xml. You use the `android:id` tag.

Your listview node should look something like this:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id = "@+id/listview">
</ListView>
```

Now your `lv = d.findViewById(R.id.listview);` should work.

Comment: I disagree with your first point. ListView is an only-child, what benefit would you get from wrapping it in a layout?

Comment: Does though, Android default to a layout if you don't specify one? I recall reading something about that.

Comment: (I had edited my comment to make it more constructive.) Think of it this way: the Lint tool warns you whenever a layout only ahs one child... Check out `simple_list_item_1.xml` it is only a TextView.

Comment: I see your point now, and yes, no benefit besides more pretty syntax highlighting. Seems I got some small redudancy issues laying around :)